# Yahoo Bizmail import contacts list into email clients

Tags: contacts, yahoo-mail, calendar

My company `abc.com` has signed up with Yahoo Business Email. Everyone in my company is assigned an email address `user1@abc.com`, `user2@abc.com` ... etc. I have a few questions:

1. It is required that user1 to be able to create Distribution List (DL) on Yahoo Business Email Server so that it is automatically available to other users. Similarly for Calendar sharing.
2. I have configured email clients like Outlook, Thunderbird and Zimbra to fetch and send Emails. Is it possible that if `user1@abc.com` creates a Calendar entry in Outlook then this entry is published on Yahoo such that `user2@abc.com`, `user3@abc.com` can see that time as "busy"/"free" when they try to schedule a meeting with `user1@abc`.
3. Was also wondering if there is any way Yahoo Bizmail shares contact list associated with `abc.com` to authorized `abc.com` users via some kind of WebService.